# Is it a coincidence when the two things do not coincide?

Tags: single-word-requests

A "coincidence" denotes that two things coincide, with the strong connotation that this is an unlikely or unexpected situation. If the situation is common or normal, it's not called a coincidence, regardless of the coinciding of the two things.

Is there a word for the situation where it is likely that two things will coincide but they unexpectedly do not?

"It is a coincidence that those two dice rolled the same number." (the usual outcome is to roll two different numbers, only chance led to the unlikely outcome)

"It is a ___________ that those two dice are slightly different sizes." (the usual situation is two same sized dice, only chance led to the unlikely pairing)

Comment: An *anomaly*, an *aberration*, etc.

Comment: @DanBron that would include coincidences, though

Comment: ... As would _quirk_ or _vagary_.

Comment: How about *discrepancy*?

Comment: I'd say *it's a random occurence* but I guess it wouldn't sound normal in a conversation....

Comment: Can you provide a definition of ***coincidence*** you are willing to stick to, and what words you rule out because they are also considered *coincidences*?

Comment: @jxh I have no idea what I've said that would make that unclear, but let me try... A coincidence is when an unlikely random outcome leads to two things being the same. A ____ is when an unlikely random outcome leads to two things being different.

Most of the suggestions so far are the union of those two sets, just words for unlikely outcomes.

Comment: Your question would be stronger if you edit it to include what words you have already considered and explain why you rejected them.

Comment: It's a *bit odd* that those two dice are not of the same size. A bit peculiar/weird/unusual/funny/strange .... when something is **unexpected**

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a coincidence when the two things do not coincide?

In the context you describe, the answer to your question is *Yes*.

Here are the relevant definitions:

> **Coincidence** *noun*
> 1 A remarkable concurrence of events or circumstances without apparent causal connection
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coincidence)
>
> **Concurrence** *noun*
> 1 The fact of two or more events or circumstances happening or existing at the same time
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/concurrence)

*Coincidence* only requires the events to happen *at the same time* seemingly without connection. It doesn't require the events to be similar. So in your example, the dice having different sizes can be labelled a *coincidence*.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anomaly that those two dice are slightly different sizes.

anomaly: "something that deviates from what is standard, normal, or expected."

[Oxford](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/stamen#xWvTPkT78XejivEb.97)

'aberration' : "a departure from what is normal, usual, or expected, typically an unwelcome one." "They described the outbreak of violence in the area as an aberration." With a more positive connotation, 'irregularity' might be appropriate: "It would appear, then, that the orchid flower differs from the more general monocotyledonous type in the irregularity of the perianth, in the suppression of five out of six stamens, and in the union of the one stamen and the stigmas."

[source](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/stamen#xWvTPkT78XejivEb.97)

Comment: Anomaly is a superset of coincidence. I'm looking for anomaly-that-doesnt-involve-coinciding

Comment: All of those seem to be similar in that they also describe coincidences.

Answer (score 0):

### About Your First Question

Of the two common meanings of 'coincidence', only one

> denotes that two things coincide.

(OP)

That one meaning is this, in variants from three different sources:

## First Set of Definitions

> 1. The state or fact of occupying the same relative position or area in space.

(*American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition*)

> 2. the fact, condition, or state of coinciding

(*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014*)

> 2. the act, fact, or condition of coinciding.

(*Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010*)

That one meaning *does not* denote *or connote*, "strongly" or otherwise, that the 'coincidence'

> is an unlikely or unexpected situation,

as stated by your question. The fact of being "an unlikely or unexpected situation" is connoted by the *other* meaning of 'coincidence', as shown by the following three variants of the definition from the same three sources.

## Second Set of Definitions

> 2. A sequence of events that although accidental seems to have been planned or arranged.

(*American Heritage*)

> 1. a chance occurrence of events remarkable either for being simultaneous or for apparently being connected.

(*Collins*)

> 1. a striking occurrence by mere chance of two or more events at one time.

(*Random House*)

So, the answer to your titular question,

> Is it a coincidence when the two things do not coincide?

is "sometimes, yes". The times when the answer is "yes" are *some times* (sometimes) when the intended meaning of 'coincidence' is the second (defs. 2, 1, 1; the second set of three given), and *never* when the intended meaning of 'coincidence' is the first (defs. 1, 2, 2; the first set of three).

---

### Your Second Question

The answer to your second question,

> Is there a word for the situation where it is likely that two things will coincide but they unexpectedly do not?

is that one word (among others, perhaps those suggested in other answers or comments) for the situation is

> **coincidence**, *n.*

as defined by defs. 2, 1, 1, the second set of three given in the foregoing.

---

### The Example Sentence

For your example sentence, if your parenthetical aside regarding the situation with the different sized dice is accurate, the missing word could be "chance":

> It is **chance** that those two dice are slightly different sizes.

If, however, the dice being different sizes "seems to have been planned or arranged", "[is] remarkable ... for apparently being connected", or "[is] a striking occurrence", then a more appropriate word might be 'coincidence' (or another word, as suggested in other answers or comments), with the meaning given by defs. 2, 1, 1, the second set of three given in the foregoing.